# Set background color on intersected cells in a table

Tags: html, css

Essentially, I'm setting a background on nth rows and cols in a table using CSS. Is it possible to style the intersecting cells in a different color?

I have the following CSS that styles the rows and cols of the table:

```
table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e4eae3; 
}
table.stats tr td:nth-child(even), table.stats tr th:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccddbb; 
}
```

Worst case, I could set the classes to individual cells in my server side code accordingly and style those...

Comment: Couldn't you say like `table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) td(nth-child(even)` to style the intersecting cells?

Comment: @chad OMG, that works! Post an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try being just a bit more specific with your selectors. You're changing each column you want, and each row you want, and all you'd have to do is to set the column within the cells. So for example, something like:

```
table.stats tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) { ... }
```